# Putting back progress bar in the new version of wget

Tags: bash, wget

Some time ago, when I did wget, it showed a simple progress bar. Now, it shows this huge line by line output:

```
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9%  194K 39s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 10%  184K 39s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 10%  195K 38s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11%  101K 39s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12%  180K 38s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12%  270K 37s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 13%  187K 37s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 14%  193K 36s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... ......^C
```

How to change back to a simple progress bar (and some header info like it always showed) without custom command line filters?

UPDATE:

turns out that when i'm not into a regular terminal this happens. The problem here is that I'm on a dockerfile build, so that's what happens, even if I do:

```
--progress=bar:force:noscroll

mongo-c-driver-1.7.   9%[>                   ] 636.56K   185KB/s    eta 
35mongo-c-driver-1.7.   9%[>                   ] 687.56K   195KB/s    eta 
35mongo-c-driver-1.7.  10%[=>                  ] 738.56K   201KB/s    eta 
35mongo-c-driver-1.7.  11%[=>                  ] 789.56K   201KB/s    eta 
33mongo-c-driver-1.7.  12%[=>                  ] 840.56K   201KB/s    eta 
33mongo-c-driver-1.7.  12%[=>                  ] 891.56K   201KB/s    eta 
33mongo-c-driver-1.7.  13%[=>                  ] 942.56K   201KB/s    eta 
33mongo-c-driver-1.7.  14%[=>                  ] 993.56K   200KB/s    eta 32mongo-c-driver-1.7.  14%[=>                  ]   1.02M   199KB/s    eta 
32mongo-c-driver-1.7.  15%[==>                 ]   1.07M   198KB/s    eta 
32mongo-c-driver-1.7.  16%[==>                 ]   1.12M   200KB/s    eta 
32mongo-c-driver-1.7.  17%[==>                 ]   1.17M   200KB/s    eta 30
```

Comment: What version and flavour of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using WSL? Are you accessing Ubuntu via PUTTY?

Comment: And what does `echo $TERM` show? Somebody is mishandling `CR` (Carriage Return)

Comment: @waltinator xterm-256color. This only happens when building a dockerfile. When not in a dockerfile, wget will get me a refreshing bar, not a newline one

Comment: @wjandrea I'm using zesty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man wget`, especially the part about

```
   --progress=type
       Select the type of the progress indicator you wish to use.  Legal
       indicators are "dot" and "bar".
```

There are subtypes to both `--progress=dot` and `--progress=bar`.

Comment: bot progress=bar and --progress=dot will give the output I pasted

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm in a dockerfile, would you mind looking at my update? It generates a new line when it should just update the bar

Comment: Is "in a dockerfile" where you evaluated `$TERM`? What about `$TERM` in the "outside a dockerfile" environment?